# Consequences of this powerful result?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, projection-matrices

Here is a statement about "complete system of projectors" :

> Let $E$ a $\mathbb{K}-$vector space and $p_1,...p_n$, $n$ linear maps.
> For all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$ : $p_i \circ p_j=0$ with $i\neq j$, for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}, \ p_i^2=p_i$ and $p_1+...+p_n=id_E$ iff $E= \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n} \text{Im}(p_i)$.

What are the abstract or concrete applications of this result ?

Maybe it is linked with the kernel's lemma and spectral projectors in reduction's theory.

It is also probably linked with quadratic forms and symmetric endomorphisms. There are Fisher-Cochran's results in probability/statistics.

Maybe we can find similar properties in functional analysis.

And finally I was wondering if there are applications of that statement in finite or infinite groups representation theory ? For instance we have the Reynolds operator.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In any case, the notion of a complete system of projectors is essential to certain versions of the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) or, more generally, [functional calculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus).

Comment: @BenGrossmann It was a property in my course

Comment: @BenGrossmann I meant that this statement can be useful for other domains as I mentionned

Comment: I misread the statement. The point of the statement (which I didn't catch before) is that a "complete set of projectors" satisfies $p_i \circ p_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$ iff the space is a direct sum of their images

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the idea that (closed) subspaces of Hilbert spaces have (orthogonal) projectors to them (an immediate corollary of the minimization theorem, a *true* Hilbert-space analogue of the literally false pseudo-Dirichlet Principle in Banach spaces), is important throughout mathematics.

Yes, representation theory, yes, spectral theory, yes ... everything. In representation theory, e.g., of compact topological groups (so, certainly of finite groups on complex vector spaces), mutually non-isomorphic subrepresentations have orthogonal projectors. This is Schur orthogonality relations (which is a non-trivial fact even for finite groups).

Comment: Thank you for answering ! In representation theory of finite group I was thinking about Maschke's theorem and isotypic's components and also if we consider the projector $q = (1/ \vert G \vert) \sum g^{-1} \circ p\circ g$ whith $E$ a finite dimensional space and $G$ a finite group ?